# How to animate bar graph data in Processing visualization?

Tags: loops, processing, data-visualization, bar-chart

I'm trying to figure out how to consolidate drawing these lines into a for-loop in the draw() function.  Basically, I'm trying to animate a bar graph, eg trying to draw each bar from 0 to it's Y value, and then it draws the next bar and so on.  I can manually add each block below, and it works fine to create each line, but it seems better to automate it.  Each line creates a bar/column.

```
float yPos = map(actions[1].presses, minVal, maxVal, height/2, 50);
line(lineXpos, actions[1].a, endLineXpos, actions[1].a);
actions[1].a = actions[1].a - 2;
if (actions[1].a < yPos) { 
  actions[1].a = height/2; 
}

float yPos2 = map(actions[2].presses, minVal, maxVal, height/2, 50);
line(lineXpos+10, actions[2].a, endLineXpos+10, actions[2].a);
actions[2].a = actions[2].a - 2;
if (actions[2].a < yPos2) { 
  actions[2].a = height/2; 
}

float yPos3 = map(actions[3].presses, minVal, maxVal, height/2, 50);
...
...
and so on...
```

It seems like I could consolidate the above into something like this below, but when I run it, it runs endlessly and creates a slope.

```
void draw() {

for( int j = 1; j < actions.length; j++) {

actions[j].yPos = map(actions[j].presses, minVal, maxVal, height/2, 50);

line(actions[j].lineXpos, actions[j].a, actions[j].endLineXpos, actions[j].a);
actions[j].a = actions[j].a - 2; 

if (actions[j].a < actions[j].yPos) { 
  actions[j].a = height/2;
  actions[j].lineXpos = actions[j].lineXpos + 10;
  actions[j].endLineXpos = actions[j].endLineXpos + 10;
}

}

}
```

I think the actions[j].yPos gets overwritten each time.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

**EDIT: Adding in my full code below to test out.

```
Action[] actions;
int leng;
float minVal, maxVal;
float a;
float lineXpos = 0;
float endLineXpos = 10;

//now draw lines
float xPos = 0;
float lineX = 0;
float lineY = 0;

void setup() {

size(1400, 600);
background(160,196,242);
stroke(191,133,99);
fill(0);
smooth();

textSize(14);
textAlign(LEFT, TOP);

String[] data = loadStrings("keystrokes.log");

actions = new Action[data.length];

for(int i = 1; i < actions.length; i++) {
float[] values = float(split(data[i], ",")); 
actions[i] = new Action(values[0], values[1], values[2]);
if(i == 1) {
minVal = maxVal = actions[i].presses; 
}
if(actions[i].presses < minVal) minVal = actions[i].presses;
if(actions[i].presses > maxVal) maxVal = actions[i].presses;
}

println("clicks min:"+minVal+" max:"+maxVal);

}

void draw() {

for( int j = 1; j < actions.length; j++) {
//println("presses: "+actions[j].presses);
float yPos = map(actions[j].presses, minVal, maxVal, height/2, 50);

//draw lines
if(j == 1) {
  lineX = xPos;
  lineY = yPos;
} else {
   line(lineX+10, height/2, xPos, yPos); 
}
lineX = xPos;
lineY = yPos;
xPos += 10;
}

float yPos = map(actions[1].presses, minVal, maxVal, height/2, 50);
line(0, actions[1].a, 10, actions[1].a);
actions[1].a = actions[1].a - 2;
if (actions[1].a < yPos) { 
actions[1].a = height/2; 
}

float yPos2 = map(actions[2].presses, minVal, maxVal, height/2, 50);
line(0+10, actions[2].a, 10+10, actions[2].a);
actions[2].a = actions[2].a - 2;
if (actions[2].a < yPos2) { 
actions[2].a = height/2; 
}  

float yPos3 = map(actions[3].presses, minVal, maxVal, height/2, 50);
line(0+20, actions[3].a, 10+20, actions[3].a);
actions[3].a = actions[3].a - 2;
if (actions[3].a < yPos3) { 
actions[3].a = height/2; 
}

}

// the white dots Object, cookie cutter
class Action {
float time;
float clicks;
float presses;
float speed;
float a = height/2;
float xpos;
float lineXpos = 0;
float endLineXpos = 10;
float yPos;

Action(float t, float p, float c) {
time = t;
presses = p;
clicks = c;
speed = 2;
} 

}
```

Keystokes.log:

```
1369064940, 0, 0
1369065060, 65, 19
1369065180, 90, 28
1369065300, 179, 27
1369065420, 242, 20
1369065540, 156, 30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the for-loop:

```
  float yPos = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i < actions.length; i++) {
    yPos = map(actions[i].presses, minVal, maxVal, height/2, 50);
    line((i-1)*10, actions[i].a, 10+(i-1)*10, actions[i].a);
    actions[i].a = actions[i].a - 2;
    if (actions[i].a < yPos) { 
      actions[i].a = height/2;
    }
  }
```

When thinking of how to create for-loops, it helps to make the first one manually, like you've done. Then you can take one of the individual code chunks that create each bar, for example, this one:

```
  float yPos3 = map(actions[3].presses, minVal, maxVal, height/2, 50);
  line(0+20, actions[3].a, 10+20, actions[3].a);
  actions[3].a = actions[3].a - 2;
  if (actions[3].a < yPos3) { 
    actions[3].a = height/2;
  }
```

And then you make the variables that would change for each bar, into a generic variable. So in this case, you find that you will have to keep making a `yPos1, yPos2, yPos3, etc.` In your for-loop, you would only need one. In the for-loop above, I've declared `yPos` immediately after the for-loop. Then, `i` will loop through all the indexes in the `actions[i]` array. Finally, the tricky part is identifying the pattern on where to draw the `line(x1, y1, x2, y2)`. I noticed in your original code, the lines went like so:

```
line(0, actions[1].a, 10, actions[1].a);
line(0+10, actions[2].a, 10+10, actions[2].a);
line(0+20, actions[3].a, 10+20, actions[3].a);
```

So I saw that there is an increment of 10 pixels each time a line is drawn. So you can write the line as:

```
line((i-1)*10, actions[i].a, 10+(i-1)*10, actions[i].a);
```

Basically, `i` is going from 1 to `actions.length`, which is `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`. And you want your line to be drawn on `0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50`. So you can write `(i-1)*10`. The second x-value works the same, but with that extra `10+`.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: yup that worked!  thanks @luisdaniel super helpful. i felt like i was close, but couldnt get over the hump for some reason.